# Is there a simple way to use FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT to validate a phone number (in a form)?

Tags: php, html, forms, validation

I am trying to validate a phone number using PHP, and would like to know if there's a way to do it with FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT instead of regex.

I need the password to enforce the xxx-xxx-xxxx format (allows '-') and max length of 12 characters.

This is my code so far. Would this work to validate any number into the xxx-xxx-xxxx format?

```
$phone = clean_input($_POST["phone"]);
if (empty($phone)) {
    $phoneErr = "Valid phone number required";
    $isValid = false;
} else {
    if (!filter_var($phone, FILTERSANITIZE_NUMBER_INT)) ;
    $phone_to_check = str_replace("-", "", $filtered_phone_number);
    if (strlen($phone_to_check) < 10 || strlen($phone_to_check) > 12) {
        $isValid = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: A phone number is not an integer.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `preg_match` instead as you can cover all your needs in one statement. This regex assures that the value must have 10 digits, with optional `-` after the third and sixth digits.

```
$phone = clean_input($_POST["phone"]);
$isValid = preg_match('/^\d{3}-?\d{3}-?\d{4}$/', $phone);
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/H2Zer)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using `preg_match()` functions for this style of regex.

**An example based on your pattern**

```
$phone = '000-000-0000';

if(preg_match("/^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/", $phone)) {
  // $phone is valid
}
```

For validating using `FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT()` try code below

```
function validate_phone_number($phone)
{

     $filtered_phone_number = filter_var($phone, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT); 
     if (strlen($filtered_phone_number) < 12) {
        return false;
     } else {
       return true;
     }
}
```

Now below is the usage of the function that we have just created:

```
$phone = "444-444-5555";
if (validate_phone_number($phone) == true) {
   echo "Phone number is valid";
} else {
  echo "Invalid phone number";
}
```